# Communication between parent and child window in wpf

Tags: c#, binding

I have a parent window which launches a child window, after doing some selection/operation in the child window is closed and I want to send some info back to the parent window (a custom class object), what's the best way to accomplish this in WPF using the features provided by WPF?

Answer (score 7):

You have many options:

- You could use a custom event in your child window that the parent window listens to
- You could define a delegate in the child window that references a method in the parent window
- You could change the constructor for the child window to take a reference to the parent window and call a method on the parent window using that reference
- You could possibly use the VisualTreeHelper class to get the parent window and call a method on that reference

Answer (score -1):

Extracted from [this link](http://newbiehack.com/CSharpandWPFXAMLforChildWindowtoaParentWindowandPassingInformation.aspx):

> The easiest way I have found to pass data from a child window to a
>   parent window is to use an application wide property. This property is
>   an object, and is not the most elegant form to pass data from a child
>   window to a parent, but it's the least amount of programming. The best
>   way to do this is using get and set accessor properties.
>
> Create a main window (mainWindow) Create a child window (in this case,
>   Password)
>
> In the main window, the child window must be shown, say, within a
>   button click. This window would have a button to do something, in this
>   case, it's to delete a record from the database.

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Password passwordentry = new Password();
    passwordentry.ShowDialog();

    if (Application.Current.Properties["PassGate"].ToString() == "mypassword")
    {
        Code, or call to delete the record;
    }
    Application.Current.Properties["PassGate"] = "";
}
```

> In the child window (Password), the property for the application is
>   set using a textbox. This is a simple window that has a textbox called
>   PasswordTextBox and a couple of buttons, like Accept and Cancel.

```
private void AcceptButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Properties["PassGate"] = PasswordTextBox.Text;
    this.Close();
}
```